# Core data object in UITableview disappears when updating object

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have this weird problem related to updating my NSManagedObject. When I try to update one of its attributes in disappears in the UITableview where its is presented and only disappears again when I refetch from Core data. I think this is caused by how I fetch the content of my entity in another thread like so:

```
[[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] performBlock:^{

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ret" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext]];

    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"menu.name == %@ ", self.menu.name];

    fetchRequest.resultType = NSManagedObjectIDResultType;

    NSArray *results =  [[[DataManager sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];




    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        [self loadWithObjectIDs:results];
        [_theTableview reloadData];



    });


}];
```

This is fired in the viewDidAppear method.

And then my NSFetchResultsController method to update the UI on the main thread:

```
-(void)loadWithObjectIDs:(NSArray *)objectsIDs {





    _theManagedObjectContext = [[DataManager sharedInstance] mainManagedObjectContext];



    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ret" inManagedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext];


   fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ ", objectsIDs];


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"dishes"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"dishes"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


    NSError *error = nil;   


    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch Failed");

    }


    NSArray *contentsOfFetch = _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;



}
```

Then in another method connected to a button in my UITableViewCell, where I update an attribute of my NSMangedObject:

```
-(void)addTC:(UIButton *)sender {

   //sender.tag equals indexPath.row
   NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];



    Ret *ret = (Ret*)[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:ip];

   //The Cell disappears if I use this code to update my attribute. 

   NSInteger amountToUpdate = ret.amount.intValue;
    amountToUpdate++;
    ret.amount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:amount];

    /*Method to Save Main Context: includes:  
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

    }*/

    [self saveCurrentContext:_theManagedObjectContext];

  }
```

How would I manage to fix this little problem, so the NSManagedObject does not disappear, in my UITableview, when I update its attribute?

Comment: Why do you use a fetched results controller here? Wouldn't a simple fetch request be sufficient?

Comment: I use the NSFetchResultsController to populate my UITableview, isn't this the right way to do it? Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: A NSFetchResultsController is often useful, if you want to track changes (inserted, deleted, changed objects) and update the table view automatically. Otherwise you can just use `executeFetchRequest` to fetch an array and use that as data source for the table view. - Is there a reason that the first fetch is done on a background thread, is it time consuming?

Comment: If the main fetch is done on a background thread then I don't see any advantages in using a fetched results controller as table view data source.

Comment: Ah, Okay. I need to have the opportunity to update the attributes of my fetched NSManagedObjects, otherwise I don't need the UITableView to update automatically and track for changes. Would it still be possible to update the attributes of a fetched object if I choose to go with the NSArray as my datasource? ... The reason I do the fetch on a background thread is for "safety reasons"  and not to block the main UI when fetching, since I do not exactly how much data I receive from my JSON feed. Since I do not have a large experience in programming for IOS yet,

Comment: I would appreciate if you could guide me in the right direction, in choosing the right way to implement the datasource in this case, based on my comment above :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Where do you fetch JSON data? Is that also done on background thread? And how many objects do you have? More than 1000?

Comment: I fetch my JSON in a sperate class, in a background thread. It is possible that I will get more than 1000 objects, yes :). Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any advantage in using a fetched results controller (FRC) as table view 
data source in your setup. A FRC is useful for change tracking with automatic update of the
table view. But that does not apply here, because the actual fetch is done on a background 
thread and the fetched objects are passed (via object id) to the main thread.

There might also be the problem, if a managed object id is a *temporary id*. If the object is saved, the id changes (becoming a permanent id). That could explain why the object is
disappearing from the table view.

So one thing you could try is to call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:` for all objects in
the background thread before passing the ids to the main thread.

Alternatively, you can just execute a simple fetch

```
self.dataSourceArray = [_theManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and use this array as table view data source. In this case, if you modify objects, you 
would have to call `reload/insert/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` if necessary.

Comment: Thank you again. I just have one more question related to memory usage and using an array to populate the tableview. Would this be effecient, to use an array as the datasource if I have 1000+ objects, which need to be shown in the tableview?

Comment: @Seya: You are right, that could be a problem. Did you try the first suggestion (obtainPermanentIDsForObjects)? - I would also suggest that you try to fetch directly on the main thread (using a FRC) and check if there are really performance problems.

Comment: Yes, I did try to use the "obtainPermanentIDsForObjects" in my background thread after I have fetched the objects, but for some reason my app crashes ? :O. Also to which state (number of objects) would using an array as my datasource be acceptable? I will try to use a FRC and fetch on the main thread and check for memory and performance. Also would it be an idea to set fecth batch size, when using FRC and the main thread? Thank you for the help again, I appreciate it :).